# Fix images/buttons to the edges of divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am trying to do achieve what is displayed in the image and having a very difficult time trying get their. What would be the best approach to achieve this with HTML/CSS while keeping it responsive if at all possible?

```
<div class="tool-div">
   <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}">
   <div>
      <li>It Does this and that and that</li>
      <li>It Does this and that and that and that</li>
      <li>It Does this and that and that and that</li>
      <li>It Does this and that and that and that</li>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">{{ obj.title }}</button>
</div>



.tool-div {
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 100px;
}


.tool-div img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you have started with? Not the whole thing, just the relevant bits.

Comment: I will add it but i didn't imagine it being of any use because nothing that I have tried has even come close to working.

Comment: `.tool-div` must have an position e.g `position: relative`. the first parent element with an explicit positioning will be used as orientation point for an element with position absolute

Comment: Although it would have been better if you had tried some of that stuff..i can answer it just post a jsfiddle for this and il update it to suit your needs

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds  I realize this can be done relatively easily with fixed pixel values. I guess my real question is how do you make something like this responsive by using percentages instead of using a bunch of media queries? Is that possible?Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3csv2p97/2/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to use `absolute` / `relative` positioning to move the elements around. *Here is an example*

```css
div{
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #333
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  position: relative; /*set position relative*/
}
div span.circle{
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  left: -100px; top: 0; /*move left half the width of the element*/
  position: absolute; /*set position absolute*/
}
div span.square {
  height: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  background: blue;
  position:absolute;
  /* quick vertical align */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: -75px;
}
div ul{
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="circle"></span>
<ul>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
</ul>
<span class="square"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, your solution was a bit closer then I ever got with my hours of playing with it. I realized that using fixed pixel values was a possible solution then just using media queries to make adjustments for different screen sizes. In most of my testing I was trying to avoid using fixed pixel values so things would auto adjust. Do you know if this same effect is possible using percents for the widths and heights of the div, image, button and list?

Comment: @Groovietunes look into the `calc()` css attribute. That might help.